# PANDAS check if a value is NaN and transfer row to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

As the title suggests, I'm trying to check if a value in a column is NaN and if it is, then transfer the entire row to a separate dataframe.

I've tried the following:

```
newDF = df[math.isnan(df['column'])]
```

returns an error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'

`newDF= df[df['column'] == numpy.NaN]`
returns an empty DataFrame

I'm thinking of trying a apply function on a copy of this data frame may work to exclude the ones with values, but I'll run into the same issue of not being able to compare the column values against NaN, so can anyone please help me?

Comment: are you looking for `newDF= df[df['column'].isna()]`?

Comment: @Ben T, I figured it out:
`newDF= df[df['column'].isnull()]`